# How do I run a function in the background of another function by using threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

How would I go about using the threading module in python? It doesn't seem to work for me, and from what I've seen on the internet, it should. I think I'm using it correctly, but nothing I do seems to work. To clarify, I want to run a function in the background (forever), but it always gets stuck in the loop, *before the thread starts.*

Here's my code, or at least a version of it that I wrote that replicates it without giving up my secrets.

```
import threading

class class1:
    def method(self):
        while True:
            # do stuff here
            # gets stuck in this loop
    def threadfunc(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.method(),args=())
        thread.start()
r = class1() #                                       These (<) three lines of code don't work
thread = threading.Thread(target=r.method(),args=()) #      <
thread.start() #                                            <
print("Hello") # never gets run
c = class1() #    These (<) two don't work either, even if I get rid of the three above
c.threadfunc() #         <
print("Hello") # never gets run
```

Comment: `target=self.method` rather than `self.method()`.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Could you post it as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the callable, not the result, as the target: `target=self.method` rather than `self.method()`.